# Problem to export Hasura metadata - FATA[0001] failed to export metadata

Tags: graphql, hasura, hasura-docker, hasura-cli

Im trying to export the hasura metadata but i'm receiving this error after running the command `hasura metadata export` :

```
FATA[0001] failed to export metadata: cannot export actions from metadata: error parsing metadata 
object: actions
file: actions.yaml
error: error in converting metadata to sdl: exit status 4:
```

Note:
If I use `sudo hasura metadata export` it works well, but I can't edit the generated files...

Steps to reproduce:
I installed hasura CLI using [hasura docs](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/hasura-cli/install-hasura-cli/)
After that I downloaded the official [docker-compose file](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/getting-started/docker-simple/)

After that I ran the commands:

```
docker-compose up -d
hasura metadata export
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem!!!

For some reason my Mac was having problems with `pkg`...

So to solve the problem I had to remove the NODE_OPTIONS env var from my ~/.zshrc (this could also be in ~/.bash_rc or ~/.bash_profile)

After that I just restarted my notebook, problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same with version 2.33.0 of the CLI, but I have no NODE_OPTIONS set in any bash configuration files.

All was working just before the upgrade.